# Interpolating multivariate data generated from different regular grids

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a dataset of dimensions `(m,n,k,l)`. The data was generated for `m` different values of an input parameter, where for each index of `m` it was evaluated a regular grid. Essentially using a nested for loop over the parameters indexed by `n, k, l`. The catch is however that for some iterations of `m` this regular grid was different. This precludes me from interpolating using Scipy's [RegularGridInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator), as far as I understand.

Note that in addition to the data I also have access to the coordinates of length `m`, `n`, `k`, `l`, which are simply 1D arrays. It is just that for each `m`, the subsequent arrays are not always the same.

So I thought instead that maybe I should use [LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator), but it is not clear to me how to do that for the aforementioned data structure. How should I construct the `points` and `values` inputs of that function? There might also be a better function in the [library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) that I missed.

Let me try to illustrate it with an example.

```
import numpy as np

def multi_dim_fun(a, b, c, d):
    return np.sin(a*b)/c+d

a_0 = 0.1
bs_0 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
cs_0 = np.arange(0.1, 2, 0.05)
ds_0 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.2)
data_0 = np.zeros((len(bs_0), len(cs_0), len(ds_0)))
for ii in range(len(bs_0)):
    for jj in range(len(cs_0)):
        for kk in range(len(ds_0)):
            data_0[ii,jj,kk] = multi_dim_fun(a_0, bs_0[ii], cs_0[jj], ds_0[kk])

a_1 = 0.2            
bs_1 = np.arange(0, 3, 0.2)
cs_1 = np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.005)
ds_1 = np.arange(0, 2, 0.3)
data_1 = np.zeros((len(bs_1), len(cs_1), len(ds_1)))
for ii in range(len(bs_1)):
    for jj in range(len(cs_1)):
        for kk in range(len(ds_1)):
            data_1[ii,jj,kk] = multi_dim_fun(a_1, bs_1[ii], cs_1[jj], ds_1[kk])
```

This is how the data was generated (by someone else, I cannot re-do it in a different way). What I would now like to do is construct an interpolation function that approximates `multi_dim_fun(a, b, c, d)` from this data, knowing `data_0`, `data_1`, the two values of `a`, and the `bs`, `cs`, and `ds` arrays.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction? All I can think of is making some complicated 4D array with a lot of `NaN` values, but I don't know if that is the way to go?

Another thought I had was generating `m` different interpolation functions with `RegularGridInterpolator` and then interpolating that somehow, but I don't know if that makes sense. I am also not entirely sure how to do it; maybe with a dictionary of `m` entries containing the interpolation functions?

Comment: I think "generating `m` different interpolation functions with `RegularGridInterpolator`" is a good option given the constrains you have.

Comment: What would that look like? Should I create a dictionary of `m` entries that all of the data and the interpolation functions are stored in, and use that as input for RegularGridInterpolator?

Comment: That could be an option I guess so you loop in `m` range to construct the interpolated functions. Another possibility you mentioned is to use an unstructured data interpolating method, like [`RBFInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator); for this to work you will have to manipulate your data and points arrays (if you want I can expand on this in an answer). These methods don't exploit the gridded nature of your data though.

Comment: I'd be interested to understand how to use the unstructured method, if that's not a lot of work for you to expand on. I think I managed to get the looped method to work but it's rather slow in execution. I would naively not expect the unstructured version to be faster or more accurate, but I probably should compare them.

Comment: Sorry I've been not able to spend time on this; I'll try this evening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the alternative approach, while very inneficient, as it doesn't exploit the gridded nature of your data, consists in simply building 1-D input data arrays (one for each coordinate) from the grid coordinates (that's what the `unroll_arrays` function does, for your specific case). In the following snippet you can check the steps. As it was too slow, note I changed the step of `y1` (`cs_1` in your code). I'm using here the `Rbf` function, by the way. All in all, not the best methodology, but has been useful for me some time in the past.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def multi_dim_fun(a, b, c, d):
    return np.sin(a*b)/c+d


def unroll_arrays(k,x,y,z):
    # Unroll (and copy elements of) arrays for interpolation methods
    kr = np.repeat(k, x.size * y.size * z.size)
    xr = np.repeat(np.tile(x, k.size), y.size * z.size)
    yr = np.repeat(np.tile(y, x.size * k.size), z.size)
    zr = np.tile(z, k.size * x.size * y.size)
    
    return kr, xr, yr, zr

# Input data 1
a0 = np.array([0.1])
x0 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
y0 = np.arange(0.1, 2, 0.05)
z0 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.2)
d0 = multi_dim_fun(
    a0, x0[:,None,None], y0[:,None], z0
    )
# Input data 2
a1 = np.array([0.2])
x1 = np.arange(0, 3, 0.2)
y1 = np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.1)
z1 = np.arange(0, 2, 0.3)
d1 = multi_dim_fun(
    a1, x1[:,None,None], y1[:,None], z1
    )

# Unroll repeated arrays for 1-1 equivalence
a0_r, x0_r, y0_r, z0_r = unroll_arrays(a0, x0, y0, z0)
a1_r, x1_r, y1_r, z1_r = unroll_arrays(a1, x1, y1, z1)

# Concatenate 1-D arrays
a_r = np.concatenate((a0_r, a1_r))
x_r = np.concatenate((x0_r, x1_r))
y_r = np.concatenate((y0_r, y1_r))
z_r = np.concatenate((z0_r, z1_r))
d_r = np.concatenate((d0.ravel(), d1.ravel()))

# Interpolating function
rbfi = Rbf(a_r, x_r, y_r, z_r, d_r)

# Target coordinates
an = np.linspace(a0[0], a1[0], 4)
xn = np.linspace(x0[0], x0[-1], 50)
yn = np.linspace(y0[0], y0[-1], 50)
zn = np.linspace(z0[0], z0[-1], 50)
ag, xg, yg, zg = unroll_arrays(an, xn, yn, zn)

# Interpolated data
dn = rbfi(
          ag, xg, yg, zg
          )
# Return to original shape
dn = dn.reshape((an.size, xn.size, yn.size, zn.size))

# Some plots to compare
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(dn[0,0], extent = [zn[0], zn[-1], yn[0], yn[-1]])

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(d0[0], extent = [z0[0], z0[-1], y0[0], y0[-1]])
```